# Unable to fit data in Keras because of incorrect shape

Tags: python, keras, reshape

I have a model defined in Keras like so:

```
model.add(Dense(40, input_shape=(4,), activation='relu'))
#more layers
```

For some reason, I cannot fit the data, despite trying many different shapes. I have a `states` variable like so:

```
[array([[0.00076   , 0.001208  , 0.00127778, 0.22222222]]), array([[0.00074   , 0.00186   , 0.00116667, 0.22222222]])]
```

Each entry has 4 inputs. However, when I try to run:

```
model.fit(states, Y, epochs=1)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 100 arrays:
```

How do I reshape this array to work with my setup?

Comment: The fact that `states` is a primitive array containing two `np.array`s [may be your problem](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9475#issuecomment-472662095). You could try converting `states` - and `Y` if it isn't already - by doing `states = np.array(states)` right before `model.fit`.

Comment: welcome to SO! Provide some more code for your question: how is your model etc See also  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask